# Android Virtual Keyboard KeyListener for getting Virtual Keyboard key presses

Tags: android

I want that on each key press I require to change the Counter some what similar to Tweeter Thing but the issue is that `OnEditorActionListener` only calls for the change while the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Done</kbd> key, Please Can I Find a Resolution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an [`OnKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) if you do really want to catch keystrokes.

However, if what you're really interested in is knowing when the text in an `EditText` View has changed you might find it easier to use a [`TextWatcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).  You would put your code which updates something based on the context of the `EditText` in the [`afterTextChanged()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)).

Comment: How to set my EditTextView to respond to these Methods of TextWatcher

Comment: What do you want to do precisely?